# Formatting union and subset together

Tags: math-mode

how to write F subset (P x T) U (T x P) in latex. I tried to write `$F \subset {($P\times$T)} \cup {($T\times$P)}`

Comment: Try `\( F\subset (P\times T)\cup(T\times P) \)` (in text mode). If you don't like the result, tell us what you don't like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As gernot suggests, using `\( F\subset (P\times T)\cup(T\times P) \)` in text mode does work.

For readability I suggest:

```
\( F\subset \left( (P\times T)\cup(T\times P) \right) \)
```